# How to configure intellij vaadin import settings?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings, vaadin, actionlistener

I am trying to develop a vaadin application with maven in idea, but all listener methods calls its own object like above

```
Button btn = new Button("click!");
btn.addClickListener(new **Button**.ClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void buttonClick(**Button**.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
          Notification.show("ok!");
      }
});
```

i want to looks like that

```
Button btn = new Button("click!");
btn.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void buttonClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
          Notification.show("ok!");
      }
});
```

how can i modify idea settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Settings->Editor->Code Style->Java, select the "Insert imports for inner classes" check box (off by default). Then IntelliJ IDEA will automatically add static imports for `Button.ClickListener` and `Button.ClickEvent`.

[image]